# What does DTC stand for?

Tags: sets, terminology

I was reading at the Brickipedia site about upcoming 2013 LEGO sets and found several in a list which were referred to as "DTC", as in "40055 DTC Seasonal Halloween 2013" found [here](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/40055_DTC_Seasonal_Halloween_2013).  What does the DTC stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, DTC means direct to consumer. These sets are typically only available directly from TLG either online or from LEGO retail stores.

Here's the original source and discussion for the DTC set that you mentioned and several others:

http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=2900